# Why React app wont reloading in Docker-compose container

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

im trying to start my dev react app in Docker and developing it with live reload.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.8.0-bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY . .

CMD npm run start
```

My docker-compsoe.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/app"
      - "/usr/src/app/node_modules"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

It starts server, but when I edit source code, it doesn't reload. What am I doing wrong?

Start React app in Docker and live reload on file changes

Comment: You might find it easier to use Node without Docker for this setup.  Since there's not a filesystem isolation layer involved you won't have to do complicated things to make a filesystem-watcher tool inside an isolated container see the files you're editing on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` instead of `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true`